# Laravel 5.6 php version conflict

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to install Laravel 5.6 in my new environment.

In my local environment, I have everything set up just fine. When I go to deploy to Elastic Beanstalk, I am running into a problem where the dependencies are forcing the server back into PHP v7.0.33.

How can the documentation of Laravel say that version 5.6 requires PHP 7.1.3 and up but the dependencies force me back to 7.0.33?

Here is the dependency list for PHP from Composer (I removed unrelated dependencies):

```
composer/ca-bundle  1.1.4       requires  php (^5.3.2 || ^7.0)
composer/composer   1.8.4       requires  php (^5.3.2 || ^7.0)
composer/semver     1.4.2       requires  php (^5.3.2 || ^7.0)
composer/spdx-licenses  1.5.0       requires  php (^5.3.2 || ^7.0)
composer/xdebug-handler 1.3.2       requires  php (^5.3.2 || ^7.0)
filp/whoops 2.3.1       requires  php (^5.5.9 || ^7.0)
fzaninotto/faker  v1.8.0      requires  php (^5.3.3 || ^7.0)
hamcrest/hamcrest-php  v2.0.0      requires  php (^5.3||^7.0)
phar-io/manifest   1.0.3       requires  php (^5.6 || ^7.0)
phar-io/version    2.0.1       requires  php (^5.6 || ^7.0)
phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock   4.3.0       requires  php (^7.0)
phpdocumentor/type-resolver    0.4.0       requires  php (^5.5 || ^7.0)
phpspec/prophecy    1.8.0       requires  php (^5.3|^7.0)
ramsey/uuid     3.8.0       requires  php (^5.4 || ^7.0)
sebastian/code-unit-reverse-lookup  1.0.1       requires  php (^5.6 || ^7.0)
seld/jsonlint  1.7.1       requires  php (^5.3 || ^7.0)
theseer/tokenizer    1.1.0       requires  php (^7.0)
tijsverkoyen/css-to-inline-styles  2.2.1       requires  php (^5.5 || ^7.0)
webmozart/assert   1.4.0       requires  php (^5.3.3 || ^7.0)
```

It seems to me that all these dependencies would not allow for an installation higher than the highest version of PHP 7.0. Am I reading this wrong?

Comment: `^7.0` means it will match all PHP versions in this range: `>=7.0.0 <8.0.0.`.

Comment: Then I can't figure out for the life of me what is keeping the server at PHP v7.0.33. According to elastic Beanstalk, it is meant to be at 7.2. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you share more context? What makes you think that the dependencies "force" something? Is there any error message given?

Comment: I am trying to deploy my Laravel 5.6 app to an Elastic Beanstalk environment. I set up the server as a PHP 7.2 server but I am getting errors like the following  " doctrine/inflector v1.3.0 requires php ^7.1 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.". The only thing I can think of is that some dependency is forcing the server back to php version 7.0.33

Comment: No. It means your PHP version is actually 7.0.33 and that `doctrine/inflector` needs a PHP version >= 7.1. Composer can't change your php executable/version.

Comment: How can the Elastic Beanstalk version be 7.0.33, when I selected version 7.2 to be installed? I don't understand that.

Comment: @ackerchez try php -v